# "copy phone data" is not working

Tags: backup, restore

When you have a new android phone, it asks you to copy data from old phone.
However, restored apps behaves as if it was installed freshly(i.e. welcoming screen, tutorials, etc.).

I reviewed other guides but they says same thing.
https://www.theverge.com/23067518/android-google-move-data-new-phone-how-to

What excatly they are doing? just reading installed app list from old phone and installing in new phone?

Comment: On non-recent phones copy data to new phone is identical to backup and restore. And a large number of apps nowadays forbid backup. Those apps are then just installed on the new phone without copying their data.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem: For example the bookmarks of by browser are gone.  It seems Google wants to force you to sync all your data to their cloud, just to be able to restore them to a different device. So all those "Phone clone" apps seem rather useless.